# Insert component dynamically in Angular 2 knowing component string name

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to insert component in Angular 2+ dynamically in this situation?

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components">

</div>
```

Where `components` is an `array` of `strings`, one `string` is a single component name.
How to do this in such a situation? I want all components from array to be shown.

This is an example array of components:

```
components: ['app-item-search-sidebar','app-item-list','app-item-create','app-item-change'];
```

Comment: You already have it explained in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). You can use `ViewContainerRef`, and decorators such as `@ContentChild` to do so. But without an actual array I can't provide more help.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard I have added the array

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngSwitch:

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components" [ngSwitch]="component">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'child-component-one'">
         <child-component-one></child-component-one>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'child-component-two'">
         <child-component-two></child-component-two>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'child-component-three'">
         <child-component-three></child-component-three>
    </div>
    ... //append other component selectors
</div>
```

Comment: in this situation I can't, because `components` is also dynamic, and I don't know whats inside, is there other option?

Comment: what all variation you would be having? Please add more code.

Comment: So the component list is dynamic right? What you need is dynamic component loading.

Comment: Right, and even in the dynamic component loading, you need to have a certain number of components in your application ready, then only it will render. You can render a component dynamically, but you cannot create a component dynamically.

Comment: @Prachi I have those components ready, I just don't know how to insert them